# java relative path vs absolute path on command line

Tags: java, unix, classpath

Running into an interesting problem
When I run:

```
$cd /projects/MyProject/
$java -cp . S3Sample
```

This works fine.  However if I run:

```
$java -cp /projects/MyProject /projects/MyProject/S3Sample
Error: Could not find or load main class .projects.MyProject.S3Sample
```

Why is that.  Did a quick look and can't find the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Is your class inside a package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this folder structure:

```
- home
  - org
    - test
      + Foo.java
      + Foo.class
```

And the code in Foo.java is a simple hello world application:

```
//Note the usage of the package statement here.
package org.test;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Then, in command line, in order to execute Foo.class, I should provide **the complete name** of the class (I'm in "/home" folder in cmd):

```
$ java -cp "org/test;." Foo
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Foo (wrong name: org/test/Foo)
$ java -cp "org/test;." org.test.Foo
Hello world
```

Now, I edit the class above and remove the `package` sentence:

```
//no package specified
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

After recompiling the class and executing the same command lines:

```
$ java -cp "org/test;." Foo
Hello world
$ java -cp "org/test;." org.test.Foo
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/test/Foo (wrong name: Foo)
```

---

TL;DR

Make sure to always specify the full name of the class. Check if your class belongs to a package. Specifying the path of the class to execute is the same as writing the full name of the class, `java` program will replace `/` by `.`.

Answer (score 2):

You should run

```
$ java -cp /projects/MyProject S3Sample
```

The path for class is already CLASSPATH-relative

Answer (score 1):

With `java`, you specify the fully qualified name of a class containing the `main` method you want executed. (The launcher will replace `/` with `.`). This class needs to be in the classpath. The argument is not a path to a file.