# Can't run java process from another directory

Tags: java, linux-kernel

I have folder A with this files:

```
- nice-proj-5.1.2.jar
- MyCLI.class
```

When run from terminal in folder A:

```
java -cp /home/user123/projects/my_proj/nice-proj-5.1.2.jar:commons-io-2.5.jar:. MyCLI
```

it works fine

but when I go to folder B and run the same command, I receive

```
Error: Could not find or load main class MyCLI
```

that is error I can't resolve. by the way when I copy file "MyCLI.class" into folder B, it works.

UPD. when provide full path and run this command:

```
java -cp /home/user123/projects/my_proj/stanford-corenlp-3.7.0.jar:commons-io-2.5.jar:. /home/user123/projects/my_proj/MyCLI
```

it fails with:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class .home.user123.projects.my_proj.MyCLI
```

Comment: You should have your class files available for java to run them, hence you are getting the error that it could not find MyCLI

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: either copy that file as you did or provide the full path of the file

Comment: when I provide full path I receive almost same error. see question update

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java relative path vs absolute path on command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266526/java-relative-path-vs-absolute-path-on-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

The class file location should be in the java classpath. Since your class is present in folder A, you would need to add folder A to the classpath. I'm guessing you are running some specific tests, ideally class files should go into a jar and jar included in the classpath.

Please refer the below link on how to add classpath:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/QandE/answers.html

EDIT:
Something like:
java -cp /home/user123/projects/my_proj/nice-proj-5.1.2.jar:commons-io-2.5.jar:.:[complete path for folder A] MyCLI